# Implementing Sign in with Twitter

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement Twitter sign in in my java web application.

I am following [this](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) manual.

1. I registered my application at [here](https://apps.twitter.com/).
2. But when i am trying to get `request_token` i am getting `Response Code : 401`.

I am using following code to get `request_token`.

```
String userUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

String urlParam = oauth_callback + "&" + oauth_consumer_key + "&" + oauth_nonce + "&"+ oauth_signature + "&" + oauth_signature_method+"&"+oauth_timestamp+"&"+oauth_version;

URL url = new URL(userUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
String urlParameters = urlParam;
con.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the doc suggests, you have to put these "urlparams" in the headers, not in the URL parameters :
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

You might also find this useful: [Implement OAuth in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964392/implement-oauth-in-java)

Comment: Can you help me how to do that

Comment: The link I provided contains a complete, clear and commented code, I think it will help you more than what I could say in a few comments :)

Comment: That is too vague. However, 403 means you should be authenticated to perform the action. Also, do not hesitate to upvote my post in case you found it useful :)