# OAuth 2.0 Open Source implementation in Java

Tags: java, open-source, oauth, identity

We will shortly build a prototype which will play the role of an OAuth client to interact with sites such as Facebook. A requirement is that we use OAuth 2.0 (knowing it is still in draft status). 
Do you know of any Open Source Java implementations of an OAuth 2.0 client library?
Our goal is to use it in our prototype, contributing to the project if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at newly released java library: [leeloo.smartam.net](http://leeloo.smartam.net)
Compliant with oauth 2.0 draft 10, same as used by Facebook.

Comment: Looks cool! Thanks a lot, we'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Library for OAuth Consumer (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731966/library-for-oauth-consumer-java)

Comment: It seems that the code libraries stored in http://oauth.net/code/ comply to OAuth 1.0, which is logical because it is still the official standard release, at least until OAuth 2.0 goes out of draft status.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this - 
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/

You have Java client implementations too.