# Working with OAuth with Java

Tags: java, oauth

Folks, please advice is there are any free available package(s) for OAuth? I need to be a client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with OAuth with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876165/working-with-oauth-with-java)

Comment: @Bozho: your link is dead, however I found [Implementing OAuth provider in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2150801/448455), [Implement OAuth in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2964392/448455), and [Library for OAuth Provider (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1731966/448455).

Comment: It is already closed. IT was a duplicate from the same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[oauth.net](http://oauth.net/code/) lists the following:

- [Scribe](http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)
- [OAuth Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)
- [OAuth for Spring Security](http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/)
- [Their own library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/)

Answer (score 2):

[Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)

Answer (score 1):

I just created a plugin for the super cool Play Framework with a sample app fully functional, hopefully it will help someone.
http://geeks.aretotally.in/projects/play-framework-linkedin-module
http://yabe.felipera.cloudbees.net/

Answer (score 0):

- [Amber](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/amber.html)
- [leeloo](https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0)