# Implementing OAuth support on a website

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I want to extend my website to support OAuth so that third party applications can access data and perform actions on behalf of the website user. How should I go about it?

Basically I would like to know how to go about generating access tokens and the database setup that should be done.

Comment: What platform do you have on your site (language + framework + persistent storage + HTTP server)?

Comment: @ArtemOboturov:  Java Spring, MySQL, and GlassFish.

Comment: In this case this seems to be duplicate for [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731966/library-for-oauth-provider-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731966/library-for-oauth-provider-java).

Comment: The link in the comment above this one is broken, it should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731966/library-for-oauth-provider-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should choose which authorization schema you will implement on your site. In your case it could be:

1. [Authorization Code Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-26#section-4.1)
2. [Implicit Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-26#section-4.2)

Then taking in account a programming language and framework you can make your choice.

In any case you'll have to configure some kind of routing for OAuth urls and redirects and a persistent storage.

Comment: OK. For Spring there's [https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2) from [http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/).